# How to prove some server sent some file over HTTPS

Tags: tls

I want to prove that some file I retrieved using HTTPS was indeed sent
by the server.  I tried searching online, but I didn't find what I
want.

How to easily prove that some HTTPS server sent some file?  It should
not require special permissions and preferably be done with only
well-known free software.  The proof should be valid as long as the
server's certificate is valid.  The proof should be able to be
validated without internet access.

An example is that the contents of a web page depends on the
geographical location of the client.  It's something funny when
requested from my IP address [such as this
one](https://xkcd.com/713/).  I want to show it to someone else.  If I
give him the link, he won't get the same page.  If I give him the page
retrieved from my computer, he'll think I have changed the page.
Fortunately, the page is retrieved from the server using HTTPS.  If
the connection uses a key exchange algorithm in which the server signs
the random bytes in ClientHello and ServerHello, I can show him the
traffic between the server and my computer.  Then he'll believe it's
indeed that server which has sent me the page, because only a server
that has the private key to the certificate can sign the random bytes.

Or how to easily prove the authenticity of an SSL server to someone
else?

Comment: Do you mean "confirm that the file was sent over HTTPS", or that the file actually came from the server? If the latter, wouldn't a checksum be enough?

Comment: @PhilipRowlands I want to prove that the file actually came from the server. Maybe others don't have access to the file or its checksum.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? I still don't understand what you're after. Are you talking about verifying the identity of the other endpoint in a communication channel (making sure you're talking to the *right* server and not an imposter), or do you actually want proof that a file you have on your machine originated from a specific machine on the internet?

Comment: Also keep in mind that SSL termination may occur long before the actual web server. There's no rule that says the SSL terminator must be the final HTTP endpoint, and many real-world setups front-load SSL termination onto separate systems.

Comment: @Pascal I've added an example in my question. Does it help to understand what I want?

Comment: I would think you could do this with wireshark + capturing session keys locally.  Then give the pcap + session key file to the other person to load into WireShark?  I think that would let them inspect the server cert and extract the content, but I haven't done it recently enough to remember if I'm forgetting key steps.

Comment: Do you control the server in question (eg can you add additional behaviour)  or do you have to work with what an existing server provides?

Comment: @Pascal Like what additional behavior? There's some web page that's only available to me, let's assume I'm only a regular client besides that.

Comment: Like a small web service to implement an authentication protocol. If you control the server/webserver,  we can probably come up with a solution; if you don't, chances are you're stuck with your initial suggestion.

Comment: @Pascal No, I don't have such access to the server.

Comment: OP+@Joe: given the session master, you can easily keep the true keyexchange (with server signature for EC/DHE) and fake the rest of the pcap with anything you want. If 'someone' doesn't trust your page file, they can't trust your pcap either. If _only_ your IP is enough to demo the whatever, not your browser/OS/etc, you could set up a VPN or more simply a transport relay and let _them_ do an HTTPS exchange via your IP to the host, which only _they_ can decrypt (and encrypt).

Comment: this would be required to implement a zero-trust peer-to-peer web scraping network, to scrape files which are only location-addressed (not content-addressed), to prevent untrusted peers to contribute malicious data. peer-to-peer web scraping would be useful to defeat rate-limiting services like cloudflare.

Comment: see also [Is it possible to store / record HTTPS client auth traffic as a signed document](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/231014/is-it-possible-to-store-record-https-client-auth-traffic-as-a-signed-document) and [tlsnotary.org](https://tlsnotary.org/)

Answer (score 6):

I assume you want cryptographic proof that the server really sent this exact response. If the server signed the TLS response with the private key, for example, this would give proof that the server really sent this response.

Unfortunately, this is not what happens with TLS. The server signs something (the ServerKeyExchange message) or the client encrypts something (the premaster secret) to proof that the server knows the private key. After that, the master secret is determined by both client and server and they use symmetric encryption for the communication. You could store this to show to someone else later, but you can just as well decrypt it and change it, so it wouldn't be much evidence that it is really what you received from the server.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're looking for a way to protect and prove file integrity and authenticity. Basically, if SSL works properly, it's integrity should be fine and authenticity is as good as much you trust remote server.

On the other hand, you could just [sign file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782826/digital-signature-for-a-file-using-openssl) and verify signature locally.

Comment: /;Basically, if SSL works properly, it's integrity should be fine and authenticity is as good as much you trust remote server./; not really... what about a man in the middle?

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. I've added an example in my question, maybe it helps to understand what I want.

Comment: @Limit If SSL/TLS works properly, it prevents a man in the middle. That is in fact, explicitly what it is designed to do.

Comment: @Xander so that depends on your definition of working correctly. You can have a company providing a man in the middle proxy to the internet... If you don't find it as a correct working. Then yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you gave, it may be easier to get the other person to connect to your computer (via webex or some open source alternative) and view it there or get the other person to connect through a VPN near your location and then navigate to the webpage.

If you want to go down the route of verifying the traffic, you can use something like wireshark to record the traffic between your computer and the server, decrypt the traffic, then extract the files you are looking for and then compare to what you saved by hashing the two files. I expect the hashing may not work due to the differences in saving a webpage in a browser and carving a file out of wireshark